# How to detect that the browser back button is disabled

Tags: javascript

I have a page that has a 'Back' button.

Currently the back button triggers `window.history.back()`.  What this means is that if there is no 'back' url then the button does nothing, and I'd like to remedy the situation.

There are two use cases I'd like to handle, but don't know how:

1. If there is no history, then use `document.referrer`.  Example, right click and 'Open link in new tab'.
2. If there is no `document.referrer`, then use a default URL.  Example, open a new tab and manually enter the url.

These two cases hinge on being able to detect that the browser back button is disabled, so that the page's back button can change its behavior.

Before someone mentions `window.history.length`, I've already looked at that and it won't work.  Open a link in a new tab and `window.history.length = 1`, then click on any link and after the page loads click back.  The back button is now disabled, but `window.history.length = 2`.

I've also looked at `window.history.state`, but that won't work either.  If you open a new tab and navigate to any arbitrary url then `window.history.state = null`, but if you open in new tab then `window.history.state = {navigationId:1}`.  Based soley off of the state, you can't know if the state is 1 because the back button is enabled or because the page was opened in a new tab (ctrl+click, for example).

Now, if `document.referrer` is null then we can assume that the page was the loaded manually on a new tab, and not by 'Open in new tab', so case 2 above is handled, but what about when the page was opened by 'Open in new tab'?

Any tips for how I can detect that the browser back button is disabled?

Thanks.

Comment: Even the last thing you mentioned doesn't work since a tab can be opened with noreferrer set. In any case, what you're looking to do is impossible because AFAIK this is actively prevented for security reasons. Part of your question suggests you're using Angular, though, and there routing is done within Angular so there would be other solutions. Your question isn't geared at Angular, though.

Comment: I am using angular 7.x to write the SPA, but I don't see how that would provide a solution.  The back button works great within the app at preventing full page reloads, but there is still the conundrum of navigating directly to the SPA and not having a destination for 'back.

Do you know of a way of solving the issue with Angular?

Comment: Have you found the solution since?